# JFK Alaska Lounge time limit with Priority Pass

Tags: jfk, lounges, alaska-airlines

I have close to a 9-hour layover at JFK (I'll be meeting a friend and we'll take the next flight together.) I'll be arriving and departing from Terminal 7, which has the Alaska Lounge.

However, the conditions on the Priority Pass mention I can stay there for only 3 hours before the flight. I have not seen those terms listed on the Alaska Lounge website. Has anyone validated this time limit?

If there is a limit, then what are some other options I should look at?

Comment: Could you quote, if possible, the relevant parts of those conditions? This is really interesting, especially taking into accout the price of such priority pass. I thought they are meant to be used especially when you'd really needed them, and long layovers are that case.

Comment: https://www.alaskaair.com/content/airport-lounge/policies-and-rules section "Access" it should state "same-day ticketed boarding pass on any carrier".  But 9 hours is a long time. Go to other lounges (international ones have more space and they are suitable for long waiting)

Comment: @Rg7xgW6acQ3g Priority Pass visitors are near the bottom of the ladder for lounge access, and I would say a frequent flyer is usually better off sticking with alliance benefits and/or discounted membership with the "native" club. To that point, faced with the awkwardness of asking someone to leave after three hours or entertaining a non-FF for nine hours, I wouldn't be surprised if the lounge dragons wouldn't simply deny admission the OP in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not listed on Alaska's site because it's a Priority Pass condition.

Whether or not it's fully enforced is a different question. I haven't tried but it will depend wholly on the attentiveness of the staff and scanner if they use one.

You can always just buy a Day Pass for ~$45, which, for over nine hours, is quite reasonable.

If you don't mind going landside, you can *try* to access the Wingtips lounge in Terminal 4 or one of the lounges in Terminal 1. You're not really supposed to be able to do this, but... I've heard hearsay, unconfirmed stories that it is possible. If they turn you away, don't argue. There is no airside transfer at JFK you can use.